# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, php, android

Here is my java code:
class UpdateProfile extends AsyncTask {

```
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("UpdateProfile", "pre-execute");
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String status = null;
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "kjljkl"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imageuri","lkjlk" ));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","klkjljl" ));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bio","lklklkl" ));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        Log.d("UpdateProfile", "Before-HttpRequest");
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_profile, "POST", params);
        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("UpdateProfile", "After-HttpRequest");

        // check for success tag
        try {
            success = json.getInt("success");

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Log.d("UpdateProfile", "user profile updated");
                status = "success";
                // closing this screen
                // finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
                Log.d("UpdateProfile", "user profile not updated");
                status="fail";
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * *
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String status) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        if(status.equals("success"))
        {
            Log.d("UpdateProfile", "user profile updated");
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Comment.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("UpdateProfile", "user profile not updated");
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Php code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])&& isset($_POST['imageuri'])&& isset($_POST['username'])&& isset($_POST['bio'])){
 // In my previous post for question, i did not give the code as I thought it will not hit this if statement. But as it confused all, I am giving the code snippet here
 if($imageuri != null)
        {
            // Insert into Db
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "UserProfile successfully  inserted in imageuri."; 
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
  // Do the same for other 2 params - username, bio, as well
}
?>
```

What's wrong in my code that following error pops up?
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
Please help me.

Comment: You don't seem to output any json when the POST variables are set.

Comment: If this is a learning excercise I can understand trying to manually generate the request. If it is not, there are better tools out there are specific to this scenario like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: your if statement is not doing anything on php. it returns no json, so how could it parse non-existant json?

Comment: i added the if statement code as requested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])&& isset($_POST['imageuri'])&& isset($_POST['username'])&& isset($_POST['bio'])){

}
```

This is the if statement it hits, and I'm assuming that all is fine with the HTTP POST. It then would return no JSON, so your jsonParser would not be able to parse anything. Try echoing some json here.

Comment: Brandon's answer gave me the hint that this error comes when we are not sending JSON response. I was sending the response when imageuri, username, bio were not equals null. But, I did not send any response for the respective else conditions.

Comment: Once I added the else statement with response, this error went away.

Comment: @Davidpostill, yes this answer does answer the question. "Try echoing some json here". Yay for unnecessary downvotes